# osCommerce images not displaying

Tags: php, windows, image, oscommerce

i really hope someone can help me.

I am hosting osCommerce on a windows server 2003, PHP Version 4.3.10.

i recently move hosting provider and uploaded my site via FTP and setup database etc, everything appears to be working correctly however for some unknown reason no images are showing on the website. When i view the source of the page i can see that the img src= is looking at product_thumb.php?img=images/nameofproduct.jpg&w=65&h=100

i understand this is the dynamic resizing however i dont understand why it still wont display the image. if i go directly to the images/nameofproduct.jpg the image will display!

1 more thing when i type the above url direct in my browser http://www.mydomain.com/product_thumb.php?img=images/nameofproduct.jpg&w=65&h=100 all i get is a page with the URL on.

hope this helps and i look forward to someone helping me!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

goto http://www.mydomain.com/product%5Fthumb.php?img=images/nameofproduct.jpg&w=65&h=100 directly and then view source .. you would most probably see an error in there too. Chances are that you have a permissions issue or whatever library that is being used for resizing is missing , i think OSC uses GD